# Why 'Meta'? Why not 'Bobcat'?

Tags: discussion, meta

I understand what the Meta sites are, their purpose in life, and their importance, however I do not understand fully why they have the name 'Meta'? I mean, why not 'Bobcat'? Could someone please explain?

Comment: You know that you could dodge most downvotes by refraining from the silly name, right? Just "what is the meaning of the word meta" is enough. Considered editing, but on second thought you might have done it on purpose.

Comment: Agree with @Sha. If you ignore the funny facial expression I got when I read this question's title, my first reaction was "why not 'meta'? Why 'bobcat'?"

Comment: It's a lot better to assume the word means something and try to find that out (it's only a quick web search away!) than to assume it means nothing, as apparently here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like I just answered on [meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com/)

Citing from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta):

> Meta (from the Greek preposition and prefix meta- (μετά-) meaning "after", or "beyond") is a prefix used in English to indicate a concept which is an abstraction from another concept, used to complete or add to the latter.

The English usage for *meta* is more in the direction of "about", hence [meta.askubuntu.com](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) is the site where you talk **about** the site [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Sorry, [Thomas W.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14420/why-meta-why-not-bobcat#comment25303_14420) said that I should ask here instead, or at least he suggested that here might be a better place for the question, and as I had no answer there yet I posted about it here too.

Comment: Well he said that it would maybe belong here so you could have asked a site-recommendation question here first to see if the question is in the right place.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda atually he suggested meta.SO

Comment: @Tim: Oh, well easy mistake to make...